Manhwa where the female protagonist is reincarnated into a fantasy game, the creator sends her back to the beginning
In this story, the female protagonist is reincarnated into a fantasy game as the female lead. Initially, she goes through the events as expected, without changing the plot. However, after she believes she's completed her role in the story, the game’s creator punishes her by sending her back to the beginning.
In this new cycle, she becomes frustrated with the male leads who treated her badly and lashes out at them. She ends up falling into a lake as a way to "reset" the game, and each time she makes a mistake, she is sent back to the beginning of the game to try again. The knight you're referring to is one of the key male leads, and he remembers the resets

What exactly do you mean by the final sentence "The knight you're referring to is one of the key male leads..."? It sounds like it's a response to a question of some sort

This sounds like A Single Round at Romance is Enough!
summary from tapas:

Romance simulation video games are usually a mess-free way to date handsome men, but after Shiyeon Choi wakes up in one, she wants out! In her new gamified life, she quickly realizes how rude the male leads are. Thus, Shiyeon decides to “Bad End” all of her love interests, determined to give them a taste of their own medicine. But despite beating the game, she finds herself back at the beginning once again. In this round, she plans to live freely and blow off the MLs... but will she succeed, or is romance in the air after all?

she goes back in time when she falls in the lake like you mentioned, and after being sent back the first time she lashes out at the mls and goes back in time to "reset" it. she thinks nobody remembers the time she "resets", however (if i dont remember wrong, its been a while) the brown haired ml remembers them.

